# How to modify the structure of incoming blobs from App center to Application insights in azure?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-application-insights, azure-data-factory

I want to parse the incoming blobs in application insights to Sql database by using Azure data factory. I am able to parse most part of the blob as it is in json format(even the nested ones) but there are some nested unstructured elements in the same JSON which i need to parse, which is unable right now.
So how to fix this or maybe is there any possibility to change the pattern of incoming blobs inside app insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way could be store the jason data as string in azure sql and trying extracting the information from it store in your table . if your jason files are too big then you can also process it using spark sql using databricks .